# link count of deleted files

Tags: filesystems, inode, lsof

I am reading in `man lsof` that

```
+L enables the listing of file link counts. A specification of
the form "+L1" will select open files that have been unlinked.
```

I don't understand why deleted files should have count `1`.

Should not the count for deleted files be `0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes. The manpage on my Debian system says *“When  `+L`  is followed by a number, only files having a link count **less than** that number will be listed.”*

Comment: you are correct. That's embarrassing, I have missed that in the manual.